# Saving graphs to the db linked to a user profile in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape, cytoscape-web

I am working on a graph visualization using cytoscape.js in my reactjs app.
What I am trying to do is to add the ability for a user to save and render graphs linked to their profile.
I am authenticating my react app using @auth0/auth0-react.
And I am exporting my graphs to JSON by downloading the graphs as a JSON file and later import
the graphs back to my app.
Exporting the graphs to a JSON file and uploading the same JSON file back the app works fine but,
I would like to implement a saving to memory/DB (postresdb) functionality and the saved graph should be tied to the current user.
The only code I have is for downloading to JSON file and uploading back to the app.
Any help with code snippets will be highly appreciated.

Code for downloading the graphs:

```
const exportJson = () => {
    // GET GRAPHS AND ELEMENTS
    const jsonGraph = graph.json();
    const { elements } = jsonGraph;
    // ATTACH STYLES
    if ('nodes' in elements) {
      elements.nodes.forEach((node, index) => {
        const sNode = graph.$(`#${node.data.id}`);
        elements.nodes[index].style = sNode.style();
      });
    }
    if ('edges' in elements) {
      elements.edges.forEach((edge, index) => {
        const sEdge = graph.$(`#${edge.data.id}`);
        elements.edges[index].style = sEdge.style();
      });
    }
    // DOWNLOAD JSON FILE
    const data = { graph: graph.json(), styleGraph: jsonGraph };
    const dataStr = `data:text/json;charset=utf-8,${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data))}`;
    const downloadAnchorNode = document.createElement('a');
    downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute('href', dataStr);
    downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute('download', `cag.json`);
    document.body.appendChild(downloadAnchorNode); // required for firefox
    downloadAnchorNode.click();
    downloadAnchorNode.remove();
  };
```

And code for uploading the graphs:

```
const uploadJson = (contents) => {
    let json;
    try {
      json = JSON.parse(contents);
    } catch (e) {
      return setError('Json file is not properly formatted.');
    }

    graph.json(json.graph);
    // APPLY STYLES
    const { elements } = json.styleGraph;
    if ('nodes' in elements) {
      elements.nodes.forEach((node) => {
        const sNode = graph.$(`#${node.data.id}`);
        sNode.style(node.style);
      });
    }
    if ('edges' in elements) {
      elements.edges.forEach((edge) => {
        const sEdge = graph.$(`#${edge.data.id}`);
        sEdge.style(edge.style);
      });
    }
    return resetAppValues();
  };
```

In summary, this is what I would love to achieve for now:

- Prevent my graphs from getting lost when I refresh the browser or
  logout of the app. I want them to persist.

Comment: No, I am not able to save to postresdb, that is what I want to do.

Comment: You should broaden the tags in your question.  There is very little in the question that is truly Cytoscape-specific.  A broader audience may result in more interest to your question.